# Centroid of Right circular cone

Tags: geometry, centroid

We know that the centroid of a right angled triangular area is located at $Y=h/3$ and $X=b/3$ from the right angled vertex, where $h$ is height and $b$ is base length. So a right circular cone is just a rotation of this planar triangular. So now to calculate the $y$ coordinate of the centroid, it is just:
$$ y_{cm} = \frac{\int Y.dm}{\int dm}$$
Now since Y is a constant it should turnout $y_{cm}= h/3$ but it is actually $h/4$. What is the mistake in what I have done?

Comment: Put your steps taken in the question so someone can find the error.

Comment: Two dimensions and three dimensions are different. The "top half" of a triangle has $1/4$ the area of the whole.  The top half of a cone has volume only $1/8$ the volume of the cone. Cones are more "bottom heavy" than triangles.

Comment: This 1/4 instead of 1/3 occurs when ones compute the center of gravity of a tetrahedron ABCD (sometimes called "simplex") with unit masses on vertices only: using the principle of barycentric associativity, you can replace the three points say A,B,C, in the horizontal plane by a single one E with mass 3; in a second step, the center of gravity of the whole tetrahedron is a point situated at the 3/4th of DE (and not on the 2/3rd).

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comment of André Nicolas: ''Two dimensions and three dimensions are different''.

For a correct calculus of the centroid, note that the radius at height $z$ (your $Y$) of the cone is 
$$
r(z)=(h-z)\frac{R}{h}=R\left(1-\frac{z}{h} \right)
$$
where $h$ is the height of the cone and $R$ the radius of the basis.
So, the volume of the cone can be calculated (by horizontal slices) as:

$$
\pi R^2\int_0^h\left(1-\frac{z}{h} \right)^2dz
$$
and the height $z_c$ of the centroid is:
$$
z_c=\frac{\pi R^2\int_0^h z\left(1-\frac{z}{h} \right)^2dz}{\pi R^2\int_0^h\left(1-\frac{z}{h} \right)^2dz}
$$

can you do  from this?

Answer (score 1):

The center of length of a line segment, area for an isosceles triangle and center of mass  of a right circular need not have the same constant in relation to maximum dimension measured from base. The factors are respectively $ \dfrac12 , \dfrac13 , \dfrac14. $

This is due to dimension of space $1D,2D, 3D $ and how the material considered as differential entities is populated/distributed.

For $1D$ it is at midpoint. if linear density $\rho$ per unit length, $x_c$ is found by taking moments in force equilibrium.

$$ x_c= \dfrac{\int_0^a x \rho dx }{\int_0^a\rho  dx } =\dfrac{a}{2} $$

For 2D similarly we can know how $\dfrac13$ point comes about if $\rho$ stands for differential triangle areal density. Integrate between same limits.

$$ x_c= \frac{ \int x \rho dA}{\int \rho dA}  =\dfrac{2 a}{3} $$

For 3D same method of taking moments is followed, $ \rho$ represents weight per unit volume aka density of differential cone elements.

$$ x_c= \frac{ \int x \rho  dV}{\int \rho  dV}  =\dfrac{3a}{4} $$

Hope you make the sketch in each case. To find distance from base subtact each of above from $a$.

As commented by Yves Douest for simplex 4D the similar solid's center of mass is  $\dfrac a5$ from its "base".

Comment: Yep, for a *simplex* in any dimension, $a/(d+1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. From this one learns that   a simplex is a generalization of the notion of a triangle or tetrahedron to arbitrary dimensions.

Comment: For the generalizations of cones, I am clueless.

Answer (score 1):

Were your reasoning right, the centroid of a triangle would be at $\dfrac h2$ as for a line segment.

The centroid ordinate is a weighted average of $y$, where the weights are the measure of the set of points with the same $y$. If you revolve the triangle, these weights change.

For a line segment, the weights are constant, giving

$$\frac{\displaystyle\int y\,dy}{\displaystyle\int dy}=\frac{\dfrac{h^2}2}{h}.$$

For a triangle, the weights are linear

$$\frac{\displaystyle\int y\cdot y\,dy}{\displaystyle\int y\,dy}=\frac{\dfrac{h^3}3}{\dfrac{h^2}2}.$$

For a cone, the weights are quadratic

$$\frac{\displaystyle\int y\cdot y^2\,dy}{\displaystyle\int y^2\,dy}=\frac{\dfrac{h^4}4}{\dfrac{h^3}3}.$$

---

Note that the formulas are computed for the shapes upside-down, with the vertex at the origin, so you should consider $h-\bar y$.

Comment: Minor nitpick: English subjunctive requires that this sentence start "*Were* [emphasis added] your reasoning right..."

Comment: @BrianTung Thanks for the fix Brian, this is a little difficult for a French speaker.

Comment: It's a subtle point, certainly.